# specify layout height/width in layout with gravity android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Vertical linear layout with weight and i have two buttons in this layout and i want to have a background for each image, but the problem is, because of weight the buttons are stretching out and i cannot specify appropriate height and weight. and giving weight is also very important. i have tried specifying button's height in separate xml but still it's the same. please tell me a way to specify weight and height to my button.

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/textbox3"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:background="@drawable/btn"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:text="button_1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/textbox4"
    android:layout_width="110dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:text="button_2" />
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `height` to "0dp"?

Comment: yes, again stretching

Comment: What do you want to do? A `layout_weight` of `0.5` suggests that you want to equally distribute the height of the `Views`, but you also want to hardcode a specific height and width? Please elaborate... I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: my question says it all clearly and yes that's what i want, who would like to have his images stretched out?

Comment: a mockup of what you want to achieve would be useful. below answers about putting layout inside layout are bad practice. if people could visualize how it should look, it would be simpler to find optimal solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it.  i remove the buttons and added two layouts dividing the parent layout in to 50-50 and then centered the buttons in those layouts.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="@drawable/racoon_tile_2" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1.0" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `android:gravity="right"`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want the buttons to have a specific heights (110dp) but still be equidistant (textbox3 to be about 25% down and textbox4 to be about 75% down)

You can't do that directly using 1 Linear Layout since Weight and Height are conflicting attributes (Weight ends up overwriting Height)

What you want to do, is surround each Button with its own layout that has Weight = 0.5 and than center that button in the new layout

Here is the skelaton of the layout you need to create:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight=".5">

        <Button
             android:layout_width="110dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             androud:layoutCenterInParent=true />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight=".5">

        <Button
             android:layout_width="110dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             androud:layoutCenterInParent=true />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `Button` inside of `LinearLayout` and weight apply on them

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
       android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textbox3"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="button_1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textbox4"
            android:layout_width="110dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button_2" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

With ImageButton, you can specify how the image will scale. Check the following example and the android:scaleType property

```
    <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/textbox3"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:maxHeight="20dp"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/btn"
    android:text="button_1" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/textbox4"
    android:layout_width="110dip"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:text="button_2" />
    </LinearLayout>
```